# prove that for an ordinal $\alpha \notin \alpha$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I understand bits of this proof but I don't understand what is meant by this proof contradicts the asymmetry of $(\alpha,\in_\alpha)$

Thanks

Comment: @Mauro: You don't need regularity for this, and it seems that the proof in question doesn't appeal to it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you include some background, for example where did you find this proof, or *what* is the exact proof. This will help others to understand what your difficulties might be.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that a well-ordering is in particular a strict linear ordering. Namely, irreflexive, transitive, and total.

Since $(\alpha,\in)$ is a well-ordering, it means that for every $\beta\in\alpha$, $\beta\notin\beta$. Note that $\in$ plays the role of both the conventional membership, and the linear ordering.

So if $\alpha\in\alpha$, it implies that $\alpha\notin\alpha$. Of course, this is a contradiction. So it must be that $\alpha\notin\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe $\in_\alpha$ is a well-order in $\alpha$.

This means that $\in_\alpha$ is a [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition) and [trichotomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)) and [well-founded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation).

I am not sure what proof you are referring to, but if you show that any of the above properties do not hold, then a contradiction has taken place.

If $\alpha \in \alpha$, then one can derive a contradiction. Therefore it cannot be the case that $\alpha\in\alpha$.